# Bootstrap Navbar and Carousel not responsive

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I've been trying to get both my navbar brand logo and my carousel to be responsive but nothing seems to work. If i reduce the screen size, the brand image overflows over the navbar and the carousel just look elongated and awkward. My code is below.

**CAROUSEL HTML**

```
    <div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
<div class = "carousel">
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
     </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="#" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
      <h3></h3>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="#" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
     <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
    <h3></h3>
  </div>
    </div>
```

**NAVBAR HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-expand-lg fixed-top">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="" width="30" height="50" alt="">
  </a>
...
</nav>
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have included the cdn in your index file? If yes try some other bootstrap stuff if they are working.

Comment: You'll need to post a minimal example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: have you tried adding Viewport?

Comment: I just noticed something in your code. Bootstrap is a mobile-first approach framework so you don't need to completely assign column classes in your divs. 
`<div class="col-sm-12">` - this div will have a 100% width in all screen resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code by adding images and it looks like everything is configured correctly. But, you may possibly want to look at how you configured your CSS.

Try adding (the most recent minified CSS):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

Also, you may be mixing different bootstrap 4 and 3 elements (I see you used `img-responsive` for your logo - That is no longer used in Bootstrap 4 it is now `img-fluid`). If that's the case try this navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" class="d-block w-100" alt="..."></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/brooksrelyt/pen/drPpeW

Answer (score 0):

for navbar,

add `navbar-dark bg-dark` navbar class in the nav.

```
<nav class="navbar  navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-dark bg-dark navbar">
 <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
     <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="nav-content" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Toggle-navigation">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="Images/img1.png" width="30" height="50" alt="">
     </button>
 </a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

for carousel,

make your image responsive by adding img-fluid class in bootstrap 4 or img-responsive class in bootstrap 3

```
 <div class="col-12">

               <div id="imageCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="2000">

               <ul class="carousel-indicators">

                <li data-target="#imageCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#imageCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#imageCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li data-target="#imageCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>

               </ul>
               <a href="#imageCarousel" class="carousel-control-prev" data-slide="prev"><span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span></a>
                <div class="carousel-inner" style="background-color:Gray">

                      <div class="carousel-item active" >
                        <img src="Images/jellyfish.jpg" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" width="75%" />
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h3>JellyFish</h3>
                            <p>JellyFish Image Description</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                     <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img src="Images/Desert.jpeg" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" width="75%" />
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h3>desert</h3>
                            <p>Beutiful desert</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                      <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img src="Images/lighthouse.jpeg" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" width="75%" />
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                           <h3>Lighthouse</h3>
                            <p>Lighthouse Image Description</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                      <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img src="Images/Penguin.jpg" class="img-fluid d-block" width="75%" />
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                           <h3>Penguin</h3>
                            <p>Penguin Image Description</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <a href="#imageCarousel" class="carousel-control-next" data-slide="next"><span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span></a>
               </div>


            </div>
```